# Calling an image with a loop

Tags: c#, image, loops, picturebox

Hey I need some help with C# Windows Form Application homework. Suppose I had an array of 10 pictureboxes and they had the names "pic0", "pic1" and so on. I need to call it in the code with a for loop, and that is my problem. Im sorry if I explained this badly, but I will try and show you the code that I tried.

```
for(int i=0;i<Array.Length;i++)
{
  ("pic" + i).Visible = true;
}
```

What I am trying to do in the loop is to loop through the array, making everything visible with the loop.
The problem is that I dont think calling ("pic" + i).Visible works. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am facepalming right now because of how simple this question was. Thanks everyone.

Comment: if you found the correct answer below, please mark it as such.. it helps other users when they have a similar problem as yours identify the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the array instead of the name - each element in the array will be a Picturebox on which you can set the `Visible` property.

```
for(int i=0;i<someArray.Length;i++)
{
  someArray[i].Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you had an array of picture boxes you could iterate through the elements of the array (which is presumably an array of PictureBox elements, not of their names) and set each element's Visible property.

```
// assuming yourArray is the array holding your PictureBox elements
for(int picBoxIndex = 0; picBoxIndex < yourArray.Length; picBoxIndex++)
{
    yourArray[picBoxIndex].Visible = true;
}
```

Another way to iterate over an array of PictureBox elements is to use a foreach statement like this:

```
// again, yourArray is an array of PictureBox elements:  PictureBox[] yourArray
foreach(PictureBox element in yourArray)
{
    element.Visible = true;
}
```

However, if you only have the names in an array (of strings) then you will need to do things differently.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `("pic" + i)` probably doesn't even compile, and if it does, it returns an object of type `string`.

Objects of type `string` do not have a `Visible` property.

You need a way of finding the Windows Forms Control that you want. Actually, you already have all those objects in the array.

```
foreach (Control control in array) {
    control.Visible = true;
}
```